# Program doesn't work when run as a scheduled task

Tags: .net, scheduled-tasks

When I run my program by clicking the executable, it works fine. When run as a scheduled task, the program does not work at all. I gave some print statements in the very beginning that it does not seem to be reaching. Not sure what is going on here. Maybe it has something to do with the .NET framework.

I'm using VS 2015 and trying to run my C# program on Windows 2008 standard R2 as a scheduled task.

I have tried changing version of the targeted .NET framework but I have not had any luck.

Comment: Do you check the checkbox 'run with highest privileges' ?

Comment: @Portekoi Yes i tried that, nothing changed. This problem is very frustrating.

Comment: Do you provide a user and password?

Comment: Is the program in a location that can be accessed by the account that is set to run it in Task Scheduler? Does the Start In folder matter to the application? Does the Task Scheduler show any errors in the history or event log? What resources does the application need to access (folder/file/database/server etc.)?

Comment: @Wiz I copied the folder to the local drive. The only resource it needs is the microsoft exchange server which i reference and use in my code. Still stuck and I have no idea why